# Vectorizing distance calculation between two list

Tags: python, vectorization

I have two list, for example，

```
list A = ['ABCD', 'AC', 'BCD']
list B = ['BCDD', 'AB']
```

for each element in list A, I want to calculate the edit distance (levenshtein distance) to list B and calculate the number of results that smaller than 3. That is, the final result should give a list.
In the above example, I expect the result to be: `[1, 1, 1]`

My codes are:

```
for element in listA:
    sub_len = sum(np.array(vdistance(element, listB)) <= 2)
```

This works for small sample, however, when the size of list A and B are two large, the speed becomes really small. I wonder if there is any vectorized method to achieve my goal, thanks!

Comment: You're looking for "vectorized" Levenshtein distance implementations? Not sure if that exists.

Comment: @luigigi sorry it's a typo, I corrected it

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I wrote the levenshtein distance function myself

Comment: 1. The fastest computation is no computation. Do you really need these results? (Is there some other way to achieve whatever you want to do using these results?) 2. This is inherently `O(ab)`. At best, you could speed up the time taken to compute a single `levenshtein` by implementing it in C, using a JIT, and so on.

Comment: You may not find a perfect answer with Levenstein, because amount of calculations grows exponentially. However a good and faster substitute may be TF-IDF and Cosine Similarity. See application described here: https://bergvca.github.io/2017/10/14/super-fast-string-matching.html

Comment: @MateenUlhaq but at least I think I can avoid the for loop?

Comment: Avoiding the for loop and "vectorizing" (in some sense) doesn't necessarily magically make anything faster. Also, since you're using np arrays, `np.sum` is probably quicker than `sum`, though that's probably not the bottleneck either.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq In your O(ab), what are a and b?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Just the sizes of the lists `a`, `b`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq could you please show me how to vectorize? thank you so much